# Symfony 5 запуск command фоновым процессом

Tags: php, symfony, процесс, symfony5

После сохранения настроек пользователем, необходимо из контроллера запускать фоновым процессом комманд, который кроме этого висит на кроне. Необходимо обработать несколько ситуаций:

1. Во-первых, если пользователь нажал кнопку сохранить, а через пару минут передумал, что то поменял, и снова нажал "сохранить", нужно убить процесс запущенный первым сохранением и запустить новый.
2. Во-вторых, при запуске команда по крону нужно проверять, работает ли он в данный момент времени от контроллера и\или уже отрабатывал сегодня, то есть запускать только в том случае, если он сегодня еще не работал.

Пробую реализовать логику с помощью process component.

Код контроллера:

```
        $query = $request->query->all();
        $filename = $query['filename'];

        $basePath = $this->getParameter('kernel.project_dir');

        $process = Process::fromShellCommandline(
                "php $basePath/bin/console test:test $filename",
        );

        $process->start();
        $pid = $process->getPid()
```

Код комманда:

```
        $filename = $input->getArgument('filename');

        file_put_contents(__DIR__."/$filename.pid.log", posix_getpid() . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);

        for ($i = 1; $i <= 180; $i++) {
            sleep(1);
            file_put_contents(__DIR__."/$filename.log", $i . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
        }
```

Процессы фоном запускаются и отрабатывают как надо. Вот только я никак не могу решить вопрос с проверкой запущен ли он сейчас.
Думал как то писать в базу пиды и отлеживал по ним, но пиды из контроллера и комманда всегда разные, в комманде всегда больше на 1.
К тому же проверку надо делать в комманде, так как контроллер не всегда будет присутствовать в обработке, а как убить процесс из комманда не могу понять.
$process->stop() принимает ресурс который мне в комманде недоступен.

Comment: Используйте очереди для запуска фоновой обработки. Очередь может разбираться последовательно. Также можно использовать symfony lock для предотвращения запуска если вы захотите продолжить использовать крон и команды.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как в итоге я реализовал задачу.

Наш комманд export, который является основным процессом, принимает на вход 2 аргумента (int)clientId и (bool)runAnyway, и имеет логику такую:

```
        $this->connectionId = $input->getArgument('connectionId');
        $runAnyway = $this->runAnyway($input->getOption('runAnyway'));

        $this->exportInfo = $this->wixExportInfoRepository->findOneBy(['connectionId' => $this->connectionId]);

        // Если запрос пришел с контроллера и по этому клиенту он уже запущен в данный момент - убиваем запущенный процесс экспорта
        if ($runAnyway && $pid = $this->exportInfo->getPid()) {
            posix_kill($pid, 9); //SIGKILL
        }

        $this->wixExportInfoRepository->addPid($this->connectionId, posix_getpid());

        $this->export();

        $this->wixExportInfoRepository->deletePid($this->connectionId);
```

В одну из своих сущностей, которая хранит информацию об экспорте, я добавил колонку pid, которая говорит нам - если тут не null, то процесс по данному клиенту активен, если null, живых процессов нет. Собственно этот комманд и прокидывает туда свой pid в начале выполнения, и удаляет его по завершению.

Данный комманд может запускаться из контроллера с флагом runAnyway, который говорит нам убей все и начни сначала:

```
    private function startExport($connectionId)
    {
        $exportProcess = Process::fromShellCommandline(
            sprintf("php %s/bin/console vk:wix:export %s --runAnyway=%s",
                $this->getParameter('kernel.project_dir'),
                $connectionId,
                true
            )
        );

        $exportProcess->disableOutput()->start();
    }
```

Так же на кроне у меня висит другой комманд, который делает из таблицы выборку всех клиентов у которых pid = null, и асинхронно запускает по каждому процесс:

```
        $exportInfo = $this->em->getRepository(WixExportInfo::class)->getEntitiesForExport();

        foreach ($exportInfo as $info) {
            $exportProcess = Process::fromShellCommandline(
                sprintf("php %s/bin/console vk:wix:export %s",
                    $this->rootDir,
                    $info->getConnectionId(),
                )
            );

            $exportProcess->disableOutput()->start();
        }
```

Чего я добился в итоге. Так как, с учетом количественных (отборный мат) ограничений api одного из сервисов, полный экспорт товаров может происходить в три этапа в течение 3-х дней. Мы в некоем подобии асинхронности запускаем последовательно этапы сразу по всем клиентам одновременно. При этом имеем возможность при изменении клиентом настроек экспорта, в любой момент прекратить текущий процесс экспорта и сразу же запустить его сначала с новыми настройками.

Answer (score 0):

**2. Проверить, запущен ли на данный момент такой же процесс, который хотите породить:**

Как возможное решение, вы можете запускать отдельный процесс, который вызовет unix команду/последовательность и [перенаправит вывод в какой-то отдельный файл](https://selectel.ru/blog/tutorials/linux-redirection/), далее, вы можете спокойно посмотреть в данный файл из вашей команды и определить дальнейшее поведение.

Следующая команда посмотрит список ваших запущенных процессов, постарается найти совпадение с "php $basePath/bin/console test:test $filename", исключит процесс grep-a из поиска и запишет в целевой файл столько строк, сколько будет найдено процессов или ни одной, если подобных нет (!файл будет перетираться, если хотите дописывать (append) то должно быть два якоря ">> путь к файлу"):

```
    $process = Process::fromShellCommandline(
        "ps aux | grep \"php $basePath/bin/console test:test $filename\" | grep -v grep > путь до файла сохранения вывода"
    );
```

**1. Убить процесс из контроллера, запущенный ранее из кода:**
Сделайте все то же самое, что описано во втором пункте, только вывод пишите в другой файл (чтобы не появилось [состояния гонки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8)), далее, вам нужно дописать немного кода по парсингу созданного файла, если он не пустой, чтобы разобрать из него pid и убить процесс.

Вы можете взять строку из файла, использовать `preg_replace('\s+', ' ', $targetStr)`, далее `$data = explode(' ', $targetStr)` и взять значение pid-а по ключу, если имеется, `$data[1]`.

Можно убивать:

```
if (isset($data[1])) {
    $process = Process::fromShellCommandline(
        sprintf('kill %s', $data[1])
    );
}
```